# PHP Session randomly dies when read_and_close is active

Tags: php, session

I am now using php and when i initiate the session i use the read_and_close flag set to true, this because in our system we mostly just do reads. Also i can say that we have functions that uses session_start and session_write_close when we want to add/update or delete data in our read only sessions.

The thing is that it mostly works, but some times (at very random occurs) it's just being destroyed and the user is being signed out.

This happens at any random time, but i can also add that the system mostly works with ajax requests. Removing the read_and_close flag makes the problem disappear.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
 {
            session_start(['read_and_close'  => true]);
 }

Comment: @user1724347: edit the code into the question rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

`session_start(['read_and_close' => true])` *does not* update the session file's timestamps.

I'm not sure how exactly PHP's own internal GC deals with this (I think it just doesn't), but if you are on Debian (or Ubuntu etc.), then the custom garbage collector script (the one that runs every 30 minute) won't see any activity on those session files, and will delete them prematurely, assuming they are stale.

(I'd say this "no touch" behavior is kinda what the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) imply for `read_and_close`, but the subtleties it may cause are nontrivial, counter-intuitive, perhaps even counterproductive, so this would be nice to have documented explicitly, too.)

Comment: Great catch.  It would also be nice if they modified this flag or added another that had the same behavior but also updated the file's timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have tested, you can still write to the session even after you set the read and close flag. I have had no issues:

```
const SESSION = [
'name' => 'my_session_name',
'storage' => 'default',
    'options' => [
        'read_and_close' => true,
        'cookie_lifetime' => false,
        'use_strict_mode' => true,
        'use_only_cookies' => 1,
        'cookie_httponly' => 1,
        'use_trans_sid' => 0,
        //Ensure this is true for production:
        'cookie_secure' => false
    ],
];

session_name(SESSION['name']);
session_start(SESSION['options']);

//index.php:
$_SESSION['blah'] = 33;
var_dump($_SESSION);//: Shows newly added variable

var_dump(session_status());//: int: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The important part here is `session_status()` returns `PHP_SESSION_NONE` and not `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`.